# How to add icon to docusaurus sidebar group or item

Tags: icons, sidebar, docusaurus

I want to add icon sidebar group or item with docusaurus. How can I do it?

Like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Use CSS

1. Add `customCss` to your `theme` config([docs](https://docusaurus.io/docs/styling-layout)), e.g.:

   ```js
   {
     // ...
     presets: [
       [
         'classic',
         /** @type {import('@docusaurus/preset-classic').Options} */
         ({
           // ...
           theme: {
             customCss: require.resolve('./src/css/custom.css'),
           }
         })
       ]
     ]
   }
   ```
2. Add overrides to `./src/css/custom.css`:

   - E.g.: In order for icons not to add tons of empty space, change layouting to be left-to-right (rather than the default center-heavy).

     ```css
     /* Override non-category links to be horizonally compact */
     li > a.menu__link {
       justify-content: flex-start;
     }
     ```
3. Add icon to item:

   - Add `sidebar_class_name: item1` to front matter of the item's sidebar link.

     - NOTE: This class name will be added to `item1`'s sidebar `li` element.
   - Add class to css file, e.g.:

     ```css
     .item1 a::before {
       padding-right: 0.5rem;
       content: url(../img/myImage.svg);
     }
     ```
4. Add icon to section: a bit more annoying

   - Add `"className": "section1"` to `_category_.json`
   - NOTE: The way the sidebar items are setup, makes it difficult to get the section icon to show up in the right place, without the right-hand caret icon to also end up getting moved.
   - Idea: The best way is currently probably very similar: add it to `my-section-class::before`, but add `transform` to move it off to the right and center it vertically with a bit of fiddly-diddling.

## Result

In this example, `Installation` has no icon, while `Item1` does:

[image]